# Best Practice .Contains C#

Tags: c#, .net

I don't quite know where to post this but C# is not my first language and I am hoping to get someone to nod their head or correct me :)

This works but seems counter intuitive - mostly because I would like to make a list and then say list contains oneCharacter but, for cases like this, it would be excessively wordy.

The only purpose of this sample code is to evaluate whether oneCharacter is in the string "YN" and to ask if there is a better (or more beautiful) way to do this.  It is not any more complicated than that.

```
    void MainGameLoop()
  {
     while(true)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Randomizing new string ...");
         var randomizedString = RandomizeString(); 
         Console.WriteLine("Please input the value, only first letter of the input will be taken into account");
         var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
         var userCharacter = userInput[0].ToString();

         // Here is the code I'm hoping to sort out.  Is this a reasonable approach within the If condition?
         if(!randomizedString.Contains(userCharacter))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Sorry, wrong guess.");
         }
         // end code I'm hoping to sort out

         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("You guessed it!");
         }
     }

  }
```

Comment: For me, usage of `Contains` is okay. It says **exactly** what you intend to check. In case you are curious, underneath it actually calls (inyour case)`"YN".IndexOf(oneCharacter, StringComparison.Ordinal) >=0`which is a search within an array.

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly this example code must accomplish, since you didn't specify. Is the string `oneCharacter` guaranteed to contain exactly one character? (What if it _is_ the string `"YN"`, or an empty string?)

Comment: @200_success -- Yes - oneCharacter would contain one character and that would be something that I would validate prior to this statement.  Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: @MaLiN2223 - Thank you - that is very interesting.  I understand you to be saying that the code that actually ends up executing is "YN".IndexOf(oneCharacter, StringComparison.Ordinal) >=0   Do you think it would be more efficient to use that call?

Comment: Please modify your Code Review request to show your real code in context. Otherwise, the question, with a hypothetical example like this, will be closed.

Comment: @Missy, It wouldn't be more efficient but it would be less readable (at least in my opinion). When you create code in C# (or other JITed language) the difference between you using a method vs using underlying code is non existent.

Comment: @200_success - Okay - I modified it.  I really only had a simple question and I didn't know where else to post it.  Is code review intended for large blocks of code only?  I mean, if it is, where would be a good place to ask questions like this?  I am an experienced programmer but I am relatively new to C#.  There are some things about C# that work but I'm not sure I'm going about it the best way and sometimes those things are very small :)

Comment: This being Code Review, we review code; we don't give generic advice on best practices. This is still a very sketchy example. Please don't simplify your code at all — we need to see your _real_ code, as per the [help/on-topic]. Also see [ask].

Comment: what is this code used for?

Comment: @malachi -- I'm just trying to improve my coding skills in C# and I am using this type of form for branching and it looked wrong to me so I wanted to see what other programmers do.  I am the only programmer at my job.

Comment: @200_success -- Feel free to close this post if you must.   Where might be a better place than code review to get feedback on by programmers on individual commands?  SO is for non-working code.   I really don't want to lose my points over insufficient code.   What is the minimum?  A large IF statement?  A method?   The help center showed one SQL statement so I thought that this was an okay place to ask.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not require questions to be about non-working code, but it does require you to ask about a specific programming issue to be solved; asking "what do you think of this?" would not be allowable there. Here on Code Review, asking for opinions is fine, but we require you to include enough context to make it concrete. Therefore, this question, as it is currently posed, is not good for any Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I like this question (for no particular reason) so I will answer with an example (OP can put it into the question so it doesn't get closed).

Say, we want to create a game which will randomize a string and user is expected to guess one letter within that string.

```
 void MainGameLoop()
 {
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Randomizing new string ...");
        var randomizedString = RandomizeString(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Please input the value, only first letter of the input will be taken into account");
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        var userCharacter = userInput[0].ToString();
        // OP's code starts here
        if(!randomizedString.Contains(userCharacter))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, wrong guess.");
        }
        // OP's code ends here
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You guessed it!");
        }
    }

 }
```

Now, my answer:

For me, usage of Contains is okay. It says **exactly** what you intend to check. In case you are curious, underneath it actually calls (in your case) `randomizedString.IndexOf(userCharacter, StringComparison.Ordinal) >=0` which is a search within an array. 
Additionally, I think you should change the order of logical conditions, using `!` is not needed in this case:

```
if(randomizedString.Contains(userCharacter))
{
        Console.WriteLine("You guessed it!");
}
else
{
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, wrong guess.");
}
```

EDIT:
One could also argue that in this case it would be better to use [IndexOf(Char)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_)
 since OP needs only one character to check but for me, if performance is not an issue `.Contains(string)` is more readable than doing

```
if (randomizedString.IndexOf(someCharacter) != -1) { }
```

**NOTE**: if performance would be an issue, one would probably use for loop instead.

Comment: @Missy I got two down votes so far :) To people who down vote: it would be more constructive if you explained in the comments why do you think I am incorrect

Comment: The downvotes are likely a response to answering what appears to be an off-topic question. It's perhaps heavy handed, but the idea is to encourage high-quality questions by not supporting answers to off-topic questions. If the answerer thinks he can legitimately improve the question - without changing it completely - then editing is the right course of action.

Comment: @MaLiN2223 -- I'm sorry that this has happened to you.  I will fix it for you right now :)